# Drag&Drop - visual problem while dragging item to other dropzone

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, mudblazor

So, problem appears only if I have additional functional inside rendered Item (such as MudMenu, Expanded panel etc.)
When I move Item from one zone to other - I see that I move not only one Item but whole container with other elemets inside (but result I need is correct).
[image]
I want to see only Item I drag (during moving).
Is there any way to fix it? I would be very thankful for any help.

Here is a code:

```
<MudDropContainer T="DropItem" Items="_items" ItemsSelector="@((item, dropzone) => item.Identifier == dropzone)" 
              ItemDropped="ItemUpdated" Class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-grow-1 "
  >
    <ChildContent>
      <MudDropZone T="DropItem" Identifier="Drop Zone 1" Class="mud-background-gray pa-6 ma-8 flex-grow-1">
          <MudText Typo="Typo.h5">Drop Zone 1</MudText>
      </MudDropZone>
      <MudDropZone T="DropItem" Identifier="Drop Zone 2" Class="mud-background-gray pa-6 ma-8 flex-grow-1">
          <MudText Typo="Typo.h5">Drop Zone 2</MudText>
      </MudDropZone>
    </ChildContent>
    <ItemRenderer>
      <MudPaper Elevation="5" Class="pa-4 my-4">@context.Name

        <MudMenu Class="action__menu user-group-app-item__menu" EndIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreHoriz" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomLeft" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopCenter">
            <MudMenuItem Class="menu-item menu-item__primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.ReadMore" IconSize="Size.Small" >
                Overview
            </MudMenuItem>
            <MudMenuItem Class="menu-item menu-item__error" Icon="@Icons.Filled.Delete" IconSize="Size.Small">
                Remove
            </MudMenuItem>
        </MudMenu>
      </MudPaper>
    </ItemRenderer>

@code {
  private void ItemUpdated(MudItemDropInfo<DropItem> dropItem)
  {
    dropItem.Item.Identifier = dropItem.DropzoneIdentifier;
  }

  private List<DropItem> _items = new()
    {
      new DropItem(){Name="Item 1", Identifier="Drop Zone 1"},
      new DropItem(){Name="Item 2", Identifier="Drop Zone 1"},
      new DropItem(){Name="Item 3", Identifier="Drop Zone 2"}
    };

  public class DropItem
  {
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `DisableRipple` to "true" on your menu, it should work.

You can also reference this thread: [MudBlazor Github Issue](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/6427)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).